# Replicate class with main method as in Java IDE within Objective-C and Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, program-entry-point

I have a simple question. Coming from a java background and having worked extensively with eclipse, netbeans or any other java IDE, is quite nice to have the possibility to add a main method to a class and execute it within the IDE, with just a click, and see the output.

I was looking for the same possibility within xcode4/objective-c but I couldn't find a way. From time to time, I like testing small piece of software, without compiling and running the whole project.

As I am still "thinking" in Java, could you suggest the proper way to achieve this with xcode4 from an "objective-c developer point of view" ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really a lightweight way to do this, but you have two options that I can think of depending on whether you want to keep the harness code you've written.

If you do, then you'd need to make a new target in your project for each class you drive with a harness, and have that target build just the class you are driving and a simple file with just the `main` code to drive that class.

If you don't, then you could make a target with a `main`, and each time you want to drive a different class, change which files are built, change the code in `main`, and rebuild.

This is assuming that you want to avoid *both* running and compiling the rest of your code. If you don't mind compiling everything, you could have one test-harness target that builds all of your classes, and either change `main` on the fly, or use `#ifdef`s or a runtime argument to decide which helper code to run.

Comment: thanks for your answer, to explain better within eclipse (or any other java IDE) only the needed/modified classes get compiled. This is quite useful when I have to check some factory or utility class, without the need of starting an application server. What I would like to avoid at least is to run the whole iOS/OSX application. By building a test-harness, could you tell me if the project gets clean/compiled each time I run the test ?

Comment: Xcode only does clean compiles if you explicitly clean the target before compiling. A normal build only rebuilds things that need to be rebuilt.